# Angularjs Resource - how to get the response from .$save

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

I'm saving some data which I get a response from my API correctly. After that, I'm trying to use that information once my .$save function ends. Here's my code:

```
auxPostulation = new Postulation($scope.postulation);
                        auxPostulation.$save(null, function(response){
                   //I get the response and the id value without trouble.
                            $scope.postulation_id = response.id;
                        },function(error){
                            console.log('erro');
                        });
```

I wanna use that response outside that call but I cannot reach it. Always getting '$scope.postulation_id = undefined'.

How this function behave?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable `$scope.postulation_id` outside the `Postulation` block and then assign it inside the block. Note that you might still get `undefined` in case the callback has not completed when you call for `$scope.postulation_id`. You might need to lay your code properly to take care of that issue, using `$timeout` or another callback in some cases.